# VB Script -- Excel "Activeworkbook" Getting Scrambled. How to declare explicit workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, automation

I'm pretty new to VBA but am trying to create an automation script that opens, refreshes, saves and closes a few excel reports.

I currently have a vbs script, but I'm encountering an issue with `ACTIVEWORKBOOK`

My issue:  Sometimes, the vba chooses the wrong workbook as `activeworkbook` and ends up saving and closing the wrong workbook.

**My Question: How can I explicitly declare the `INCENTIVE REPORT` instead of using `ActiveWorkBook`?**

My code is as follows:

```
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

**'THIS IS THE MASTER BOOK WHICH OPENS ALL OF THE OTHER FILES AND KEEPS TIMESTAMPS OF WHEN THEY WERE LAST SAVED**

objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Analyst_Reporting\Automation\DAILY AUTOMATION BOOK.xlsm")  


objExcel.Visible = True

**'THIS OPENS AN "INCENTIVE REPORT"**

objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.INCENTIVE"  

 **'THIS REFRESHES THE "INCENTIVE REPORT"**

objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.helloworld" 

***'THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS.  INSTEAD OF SAVING THE INCENTIVE REPORT (WHICH SHOULD BE "ACTIVEWORKBOOK"), IT SAVES AND CLOSES THE "DAILY AUTOMATION BOOK" AND CRASHES THE REPORT***

objExcel.**ActiveWorkbook**.Save   

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)

objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.INCENTIVETIMESTAMP"

objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEtest"


objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.ACE"

objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.helloworld"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)

objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.ACETIMESTAMP"

objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEtest"




objExcel.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Presumably `ThisWorkbook.Incentive` should be rewritten to return a workbook object. `Workbooks.Open` returns a workbook reference that you need to capture.

Comment: I'm a big noob. Plz forgive.    

I am running this from a .vbs script I made in notepad.  I couldn't use "workbooks.open" because the excel file is password protected (i was having trouble with that).  

So instead, I'm running the "INCENTIVE" macro in the master book to open up the incentive report and punch the password in, read-only false, etc. etc.

Is there some way to declare a workbook explicitly from this external notepad file?  (god im such a scrub)

Comment: Make `Incentive` a `Function` that returns a `Workbook` object.

Comment: Perhaps a macro that can reside the master workbook to say something like..

"If this workbook is the active workbook, then make the other workbook the active workbook"

Comment: No there's no need to do that. You need `Function Incentive() As Workbook`, not `Sub`.

Comment: `Set objSheet = GetObject("C:\folder\myworkbook.xlsx!Sheetname")` instead of `CreateObject` with the application object. To access `Run` use `objSheet.Application.run`. Doc objects follow COM rules but Excels App object doesn't quite for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I'm sure what you guys are saying makes sense, but I have little to no VBA experience, and I just can't get it/don't understand.  Is there a way to simply say "activate workbook (filepath)" prior to the "activeworkbook.save // activeworkbook.close" steps?  That seems like the easiest bandaid solution for me which requires the lowest amount of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help guys, I was able to come up with a solution that worked for me.

The original issue is that the activeworkbook was changing unexpectedly. To fix this, I declared "activeworkbook = WBK" and used the WBK variable instead of using "activeworkbook".

EXAMPLE BELOW:

```
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")



objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Analyst_Reporting\Automation\DAILY AUTOMATION BOOK.xlsm") 


objExcel.Visible = True



objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.INCENTIVE"
set wbk = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook 'SETTING WBK = ACTIVEWORKBOOK HERE
objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.helloworld"
wbk.save                          'CALLING WBK INSTEAD OF "ACTIVEWORKBOOK.SAVE"
wbk.close(0)                      'CALLING WBK INSTEAD OF "ACTIVEWORKBOOK.CLOSE"
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.INCENTIVETIMESTAMP"
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEtest"


objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.ACE"
set wbk = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.helloworld"
wbk.save
wbk.close(0)
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.ACETIMESTAMP"
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEtest"

objExcel.Run "ThisWorkbook.CLOSINGRATIO"
set wbk = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.helloworld"
wbk.save
wbk.close(0)
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.CLOSINGRATIOTIMESTAMP"
objExcel.Run "Thisworkbook.SAVEtest"
```

---

This worked quite well for me, although I'm sure there are more elegant solutions :)

Thanks again!